# SQL from giving syntax error after IF condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Could someone guide me where I am going wrong in this query.

```
SELECT ID, 
   IF REFERENCE_ID like '%[0-9]%' 
        THEN 
           REFERENCE_ID 
        ELSE
           ''
   END
FROM TABLE
```

I actually have a table with the reference_id column having sometimes numeric values and sometimes with just "***-*-**" or "**_-**" thus I wanted to display blank in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

You need a CASE statement to achieve that:

```
SELECT ID,
        CASE
            WHEN REFERENCE_ID like '%[0-9]%' THEN REFERENCE_ID 
        ELSE ''          
   END AS ReferenceId
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:

<kbd>IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)</kbd>

```
SELECT ID,
   IF (REFERENCE_ID REGEXP '[0-9]', REFERENCE_ID, '') 
FROM   tbl;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=acd0e6341cbe4ce3ae872fdeb5451da2)*

Comment: `IF (REFERENCE = '%[0-9]%', REFERENCE_ID, '') ` - you need an `=` in there I think.

Comment: are you guess missing the ID in the REFERENCE under IF, and I did try this but it gives syntax error on REFERNCE_ID

Comment: @McNets I did try this but it was giving me syntax error on the REFERNCE_ID after the condition.

Comment: The solution given by @Thanos Markau with the case condition is working, any idea why the above case is not.

Comment: Thanks @McNet I guess there is some restriction with Sybase for this.

Comment: @AravindS Sybase? You tagged as MySql

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP` and `CASE` statement :

```
case WHEN REFERENCE_ID REGEXP '[0-9]'
     THEN REFERENCE_ID
      ELSE ''
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the [*IF* flow control structure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) as expression. That isn't what [flow control statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-statements.html) are meant for (emphasis mine):

> MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT
>   constructs for **flow control within stored programs**. It also
>   supports RETURN within stored functions.

There's a similarly named [`IF` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) you could be using in this context, though I particularly find [`CASE ... END` structures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) more readable. (See other answers for details on that.) Also, I'd avoid using empty strings to mean "blank". That's what `NULL` normally means and if your program needs to make a distinction between empty and null it's a sign that something in your design isn't totally clear.